# Thumbnails regenerate wp_generate_attachment_metadata

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I'm importin pictures via FTP and create custom recorss in mySQL via insert.
I'm trying to make a cron job to regenerate thumbnails.

This is what i came up to.. but i doesnt work.

```
add_action( 'my_hook_regenerateimages', 'regenerateThumbnails' );

function regenerateThumbnails() {

//$images = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%' AND DATE(´post_date´) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)" );
//$images = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%'");
$images = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%' AND post_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)" );

foreach ( $images as $image ) {
    /*$id = $image->ID;
    $fullsizepath = get_attached_file( $id );

    if ( false === $fullsizepath || !file_exists($fullsizepath) )
        return;

    if ( wp_update_attachment_metadata( $id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $id, $fullsizepath ) ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    */
    $fullsizepath = get_attached_file( $image->ID );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $image->ID, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $image->ID, $fullsizepath ) );      
}
}
```

Comment: No they are. I'm inserting them in database. Everything is OK, pictures are visible in products. Just this thumbnails that i cant figure out :(.

Comment: Your code seems fine. But you do have `global $wpdb;` in the actual `regenerateThumbnails()` ?

Comment: nope. so i guess thats the problem. 
i added "global $wpdb;" and now i think is ok.

Comment: You could actually check the PHP/server error logs to see what happened, but I'm now quite sure it was because you did not load the `$wpdb` from the function. :)

Comment: I was getting this error:
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/xxxxxx/domains/xxxxxx.si/private_html/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-imagick.php on line 358

so i added this line in .htaccess
    php_value max_execution_time 300

Comment: Don't process all results at once - try with 10 and increase as necessary - the exact value would depend on your server's capabilities (how much processes/requests it can handle per session, etc.). You should also (modify the SQL command and) target only certain attachments, for example, those having a specific custom field - and after the thumbnails are regenerated, delete the custom field (so that the attachments wouldn't be included in the next cron job). However, it might be easier for you to try this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).